# How to decorate $modalInstance in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-decorator

Would it be possible or is there currently a way to intercept all modal instances on creation and bind to its promise values?

I would ideally like to create an Angular decorator to do this but there is no $modalInstance provider available on application bootstrap, only $modal is available.

I would like to do this to perform some common system wide operations whenever a modal is opened in my application.

Thanks

Comment: So you just want to be notified about every modal open?

Comment: Yes notified on open as well as close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is optimal solution for this task, but this is how I used to solve this when I had to do the same thing. `$modal` service defines another helper service called `$modalStack` which has some useful methods. You can watch its [`getTop`](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js#L295) method:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $modalStack) {
    $rootScope.$watch(function() {
        return $modalStack.getTop();
    }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            if (newValue) {
                console.log('opened', newValue);
            }
            else {
                console.log('closed', oldValue);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/sm6jGqlITxgQkRt3EHXN?p=info

Comment: Thanks @dfsq. Not optimal as you say. Id like to see if there are any other solutions out there.

Comment: Sure, I'm also interested.